# Acer T231H Multitouch functions not recognized in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, touch

The title pretty much describes it all..
According to the information of the Acer T231H Monitor, it should be able to detect simple gestures.

When tracing Multitouch.supportsGestureEvents it returns false. Same goes for supportsTouchEvents.

Is this because Windows wants to use the monitor as a mouse? Google doesn't turn up any useful information about this problem. So does anyone know the solution/reason?

Note, I have installed the monitor driver from the Acer website.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using Windows 7 go to Computer -> Properties. You'll see Pen and Touch, and if it says that input is not available check if you connected your monitor to USB and installed drivers.

Comment: Yeah I'm using Windows 7. The monitor is detected and the (windows) drivers for touch are installed.
When using the monitor normally, it uses my finger as the mouse.

Comment: Does your monitor support multi-touch or is it only single touch? Maybe check if there is a driver update.

Comment: It should support it! Well, at least according to the website of Acer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is easy:

First I tried it in Flash CS5 an also nothing happens, because it regulary only compile projects there for Flashplayer 10. But only the Flashplayer 10.1 and higher supports gesture- and touchevents!

My idea to patch my Flash CS5 with a new export-value (http://blogs.adobe.com/rgalvan/2011/11/adding-fp11-support-to-flash-pro-cs5-and-cs5-5.html) didn't work as well.

But I didn't give up, and I used the FlexSDK to compile it and it works fine!!!

Comment: Really? :o I didn't even think about that possibility! I've been using gestureworks.. but since that's only a trial.. I'm going to check it as soon as I can :)